# Hadoop "hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave" command deprecated

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

used **`Sudo jps`** to see the daemons running. and found node manager not running.

So tried, **`sudo service hadoop master stop`** to stop and when I tried to restart it got restarted. However, when I'm giving this command **`hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave`** its saying its deprecated. I tried this as well **`hadoop hdfsadmin -safemode leave`**

But, getting

> Error: Could not find or load main class hdfsadmin

Answer (score 2):

hadoop dfsadmin is depricated, however it should work. Correct usage is `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave`

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Safemode

Answer (score 0):

hadoop dfsadmin is depricated, however it should work. Correct usage is hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
Safe mode is OFF

First switch from user to root and su - hdfs .
1) hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
Result : safe mode is OFF